# Business rules on model layer

Tags: jakarta-ee, bean-validation

In my class I need to validate and save the status of movimentation. I don't know where put this validation. I think I'd better put it on model layer and not in my bean.

I'm doing this:

1 - Movimentacao

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class Movimentacao implements Serializable, Entidade {

    ...

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @NotNull
    @DecimalMin("0.01")
    private BigDecimal valor;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @NotNull
    @DecimalMin("0.01")
    private BigDecimal valorQuitado;    

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable=false, length=1)
    private MovimentacaoStatus status;

    ...

    public void setStatus(MovimentacaoStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

2 - form.xhtml

```
<!-- show only on edit mode (status not null) -->
<h:outputText id="status" value="#{movimentacaoBean.movimentacao.status.descricao}" rendered="#{movimentacaoBean.movimentacao.status ne null}" />
```

3 - MovimentacaoBean

```
public String salvar() throws Exception{

    movimentacaoService.salvar(movimentacao);
    this.movimentacao = null;
    this.todos = null;

    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Movimentação salva com sucesso", ""));
    context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);

    return "pretty:financeiro-lista";

}
```

**The status isn't defined by user.** Where should I put the validation? On setStatus?

If I change setStatus to (for example):

```
public void setStatus() {
 //example. The real Business rules are other.
 this.status = MovimentacaoStatus.P;
}
```

or

```
public void setStatus(MovimentacaoStatus status) { //status variable never used...
 //example. The real Business rules are other.
 this.status = MovimentacaoStatus.P;
}
```

I receive the error below (because MovimentacaoBean don't received status from form.xhtml):

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column
>   'status' cannot be null

How and where I should put the business rules for status? The same question applies when I edit the record. Depending on the "valor" and "valorQuitado" the status may to change. The difference on edit mode is that the status attribute is visible on form.xhtml (Read only - outputText)

Comment: You should put the validation in your bean. Before you perform save on Movimentacao. You can also make required on the field (With enum a selectOneMenu is best choice).

Comment: @Milkmaid Maybe on MovimentacaoService is the better, right? Because if I need to use tha same classes on other technology that JSF, I will not have coupling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. I usually put it into bean. But it makes sense to make a check in service layer as well using exceptions. (If you plan different frontend etc) 
Downside could be that if you have a lot of validation and you want to give proper info to end user it might be a bit more tricky.

**Therefore**:I would recommend to do the check on both places.

- In bean validate every input with proper information to the end user.
- In service rise the general exception and catch it in bean.

Basic rules:

- Make sure you do not use bean stuff in service (like faces context, or beans itself etc).
- Make sure you do the check before the database rise exception. (Runtime)

Check this as well:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407840/validation-in-spring-mvc-in-controllers-or-service-layer)